# html/php random image generator - align image based on screen size

Tags: php, html, css, image

Hi everyone thank you for your time

Please help me fix the html code below i am trying to achieve every time user/browser refreshes the page the image refreshed (random order) at the moment it is working fine. however the image does not get resize automatically to fit the screen, in other words if image is bigger than the screen then i have to scroll down/right to see the image  please help me fix this driving me nuts

I have to folder called 
domain.com/index.php 
domain.com/images folder which contains all the images

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:transparent;">

<style type="text/css">
.myImage
{
  //  margin: auto;
  //  display: block; 
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  //  padding: 0px;
  //object-fit: contain
  //  overflow-x: auto;
  //   white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>


<?php 
$folder = opendir(images);

$i = 0;
while(false !=($file = readdir($folder))){
if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
    $images[$i]= $file;
    $i++;
    }
}
$random_img=rand(0,count($images)-1);
echo '<img src="images/'.$images[$random_img].'" alt="image" class="myImage" ';
  
   ?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? It is not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're not closing your  tag. You're missing the closing `>`. I know these things are sometimes easy to miss when you've been working on something for awhile.

It should look like this:

```
echo '<img src="images/'.$images[$random_img].'" alt="image" class="myImage">';
```

You could possibly be able to solve your problem but putting this section of HTML in another `div` and defining a width for that `div` so that it is smaller than your screen size.

For example:

```
echo '<div class="imgbox">';
echo '<img src="images/'.$images[$random_img].'" alt="image" class='myImage'>';
echo '</div>';
```

and then add CSS for that using either fixed pixels or responsive percentages

```
.imgbox{
  width: px OR %;
  height: px OR %;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:transparent;">

<style type="text/css">
.myImage{
  //  margin: auto;
  //  display: block; 
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  //  padding: 0px;
  //object-fit: contain;
  //  overflow-x: auto;
  //   white-space: nowrap;
}

.imgbox{
      width: set px OR % values here;
      height: set px OR % values here;
    }
</style>


<?php 
$folder = opendir(images);

$i = 0;
while(false !=($file = readdir($folder))){
if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
    $images[$i]= $file;
    $i++;
    }
}
$random_img=rand(0,count($images)-1);
echo '<div class="imgbox">';
    echo '<img src="images/'.$images[$random_img].'" alt="image" class="myImage">';
    echo '</div>';

            ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show me how it is done, 
like where to add the div code and css code as i am not a programmer 

Thank you Vel i added the >

Comment: I edited my answer to show you where they would fit in your current code.

Comment: Hopefully that works for you. You might have to add things to them `.imgbox` class CSS to make it centered on the screen or where ever you want it to be placed. I just put in the width and height options for you and you will have to adjust it further.

Comment: Here is a list for reference for styling if you're unfamiliar with CSS at all [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp)

Comment: it is not working :(

.imgbox{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
HTTP ERROR 500 - it is not loading any images

Comment: That's a server error and the CSS shouldn't be having any effect on that. You might have to refresh your page. [link](https://www.westhost.com/knowledgebase/display/WES/What+Is+A+500+error) Are you working off a local host or are you doing this on another host you're using?

Comment: i am doing this on another host, i am getting this error in the log

[07-Feb-2018 22:14:54 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/ajsaini/public_html/domain.com/index.php on line 36

Comment: replace `echo '</div>';` and `echo '<div class="imgbox">';` since I forgot the semicolons

Comment: @IncredibleHat that's what he probably did. Then I foolishly copied and pasted while I was writing it and forgot to add the `;` haha. Hopefully it works for you now Aj

Comment: Hi incredible, i added the semi colon
[07-Feb-2018 22:18:25 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/ajsaini/public_html/domain.com/index.php on line 36

Comment: Aj, I updated my answer to include the two missing semicolons in the full code for you. Sorry about making that mistake.

Comment: Hi guys i copied your code above and ran same error again

.imgbox{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

[07-Feb-2018 22:23:35 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'myImage' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/ajsaini/public_html/domain.com/index.php on line 37

Comment: What specifically is on line 37?

Comment: </html> i am using notepad++

Comment: I skimmed through the code and I see a missing `;` on this commented out piece in the CSS `//object-fit: contain`. It should be `//object-fit: contain;` for whenever you're going to use that. I'll update my answer once again to include that

Comment: You shouldn't have to touch the `</html>` at all. Your error is referencing the  `myImage` in your CSS I believe.

Comment: i tried that as well infact i got rid of all the commented lines of code but still no luck

Comment: </html> is the default block
i tried the original file that one is working, you can change the class name if you think that makes difference

Comment: ye sir can i send my file if you think that helps index.php

Comment: I edited my answer again for you. There was an issue with the quotes on this `echo '<img src="images/'.$images[$random_img].'" alt="image" class="myImage">';`, but I fixed it. There was a single quote where a double quote should've been.

Comment: [07-Feb-2018 22:39:39 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'myImage' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/ajsaini/public_html/domain.com/index.php on line 30

line 30 :   $images[$i]= $file;

Comment: Alright, to find out why this is messing up, let's work backwards so we can start at the code you started with. Remove the CSS `.imgbox{
      width: set px OR % values here;
      height: set px OR % values here;
    }`. If you're still getting an error then remove the `echo '</div>';` and echo `'<div class="imgbox">';` and that should bring it back to its original state. See if you're getting any errors there. If not, then build it back up again and see which line is causing the issue.

Comment: Your error is saying you're missing a `,` or `;` on `$images[$i]= $file;`, but that has a `;` unless it was accidentally deleted.

Comment: ok it is finally working thank you 
however not aligning based on the screen size

Comment: I want the width to be 100%

Comment: What do you have for the CSS so far? This issue now just needs to be corrected by using CSS to align and size things.

Comment: <style type="text/css">
.myImage{
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.imgbox{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
</style>

Comment: Thanks for all your help Vel really appreciate it

Comment: Try something like this `.myImage{ height: 100%; width: 100%; } 
.imgbox{ height: 80%; width: 80%; } ` and then just play around with percentages and `auto` to see what works best for you

Comment: Here's some more information on CSS sizing for further reference [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp)

Comment: And here's some information of responsive web design images [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp)

Comment: Hi vel,
Thank you for all your help i really appreciate your patience, 
the problem i was having was my my file kept getting saves as index.html when it should have been index.php windows 10 hides known extension types 

Thank You once again

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you finally figured it out in the end :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this. I tested on my local dev box and appeared OK. Hope this helps. You would have to make a few small tweaks to directory paths, but should work OK. The path to the directory containing the images must be the full path. "glob" is a PHP function that returns an array of the contents of a directory using pattern matching (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .myImage
    {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height:100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:transparent;">
    <?php
        // Grab the contents of the directory using a file matching pattern.
        $folder = glob(__DIR__.'/html/ImageFiles/*.jpg');
        if (false === $folder || empty($folder)) {
            // Show some default image.
        } else {
            // Randomize the array.
            shuffle($folder);
            // Grab the first element off the array.
            $random_img = array_pop($folder);
            // In the src= replace the full file path to make absolute path.
            echo '<img src="'.str_replace(__DIR__, '', $random_img).'" alt="image" class="myImage">';
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $folder = glob(__DIR__.'/html/ImageFiles/*.jpg');
 $folder = http://example.com/images(__DIR__.'/html/ImageFiles/*.jpg');

do you want me to change it to like this

Comment: $folder = glob(__DIR__.'example.com/Images/*.jpg');

sorry i mean is the above correct

Comment: Let's say your directory structure looks like this, where index.php and images directory are in the same parent directory:
/index.php (the file containing the code above)
/images/image.jpg

Then you would have:
    $folder = glob(__DIR__.'/images/*.jpg');

Hope this helps -

Comment: Sorry, keeps removing my underscores and formatting.

`$folder = glob(__DIR__.'/images/*.jpg');`